# javax.servlet.ServletException: WFLYWELD0044: Error injecting resource into CDI managed bean. Can't find a resource named . .

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly-10

the error is occurring in a WildFly 10 container.
The whole error looks like:

```
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/com.maggioni.Bean.InfoBean/infoCreator -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.B77.EJBStatefulBean-Bidder-Demo-web.env."com.maggioni.Bean.InfoBean".infoCreator
at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
a...

[0m[31m13:45:26,716 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-8) UT005023: Exception handling request to /web/infobean.jsf: javax.servlet.ServletException: WFLYWELD0044: Error injecting resource into CDI managed bean. Can't find a resource named java:comp/env/com.maggioni.Bean.InfoBean/infoCreator
```

The Infobean.jsf ist injecting a EJB like following:

```
@Named("infobean")
@SessionScoped
public class InfoBean implements Serializable{     
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB
    private InfoCreator infoCreator;

    public String getInfo() {
        return infoCreator.getInfo();
    }
}
```

and the EJB Infocreator looks like

```
@Stateful 
public class InfoCreator implements InfoInterface{

    @Override
    public String getInfo() {
       return "Info";
    }
}
```

let me know if you want to know more details, I'm not really very sure what need to be posted here.

The GitHub repository is [here](https://github.com/kenparker/ejb-in-ear.git)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you trying to inject a stateful EJB into your CDI bean?
Given the code that you posted I don't see any reason to use an EJB (even less for a stateful one).

Simply remove the @Stateful annotation and inject it like this:

```
@Named("infobean")
@SessionScoped
public class InfoBean implements Serializable{     
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private InfoCreator infoCreator;

    public String getInfo() {
        return infoCreator.getInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is just a simplified version of the real application. I'm just trying to test Stateful EJB

Comment: Ok I didn't understood that. But depending on your real application needs, I would still consider whether you should use it or not. With the new version of CDI, the cases for which you need an EJB are becoming less frequent.